# "All other JavaScript code must be between the <body> tags of the page": Why?

Tags: javascript, google-app-engine

I'm reading over the [Google AppEngine Channel API](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/channel/javascript#building_your_javascript_client) and it states that the rest of the page's javascript must reside in the body.  I understand why this would need to be included before anything else that uses it, but why would all the other javascript need to reside in the body?

in other words, what would be the problem with:

```
<head>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/_ah/channel/jsapi"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="/js/myapp.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
  ...
</body>
```

Comment: As opposed to the `head`?

Comment: @FelixKling -- Yes.  As opposed to the head.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that because jsapi is known to block execution of javascript in some cases/old browsers, so putting all other js in the body won't halt page rendering.

Also, I assume the docs was trying to say: "All other JavaScript code [that refers to it]..."